# How to enable code hinting for css in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sublimetext2, code-hinting

I am new to rails and using Sublime Text 2 for my code writing. It's working well with `.erb` files but when it comes to writing css in `scss` files I am not sure how I enable code hinting for css. Like when I want to write `font` it will display all font name attributes like what we have in `Dreamweaver`. How could I do this?

Note: I already googled and found some package/plugins are available, but I am not sure which one to use and How to use as I am new to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done it myself with `scss` but here is my suggestion:

1. Install wbond's [package control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control)
2. Restart Sublime
3. Hit `ctrl + shift + p`
4. Type `install package` and hit `enter`
5. Type `scss` and hit `enter`
6. Restart Sublime

You should now get more functionality for `.scss` files. See [here](https://github.com/danro/SCSS-sublime) for more documentation on the package.

PS. package control is the **bomb** for Sublime :)

Comment: Awsome..its all like the way you mentioned ...thx a lot +1 and  accepted :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Package control rocks my world daily; glad to share the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jondlm mentioned, make sure you also have CSS syntax selected for scss. To do this, hit ctrl+shift+p then type 'CSS' and select 'Set syntax: CSS' which should be the first option :)